# Knowing which points belong to which cluster in DBSCAN

Tags: r, cluster-computing, noise, outliers, dbscan

I need to use DBSCAN to cluster betting odds of soccer matches.

The data consists of :

ID, Home Team, Away Team, Date, Time, Home Winning Odds, Draw Odds and Away Winning Odds.

I need Home Winning Odds, Draw Odds and Away Winning Odds for the DBSCAN clustering because I want to find outliers using the noise cluster.

However I have no means of knowing those points to which record they belonged.]

I am working with GNU R to use the algorithm using the package fpc

Comment: The R `fpc` implementation is really "limited", unfortunately.

Comment: Does this mean that what I'm asking cannot be done?

Comment: Sure it can, but you may need to look at, understand, and optimize the source.

Answer (score 0):

From the DBSCAN pseudocode:

```
add P to cluster C
```

At this point, you should store which points belong to which cluster, obviously; in whichever data structure you prefer (could be a set, or an cluster assignment array).